# Why is C++17 adding attributes to namespaces and enumerators?

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces, standards

As in the question states, I know there are going to be attributes for namespaces and enumerators in C++17. How will this influence our code? What are those attributes and what will they allow us to do? I could not find any good resource for understanding this new feature.

Comment: Well, now you can deprecate a namespace or enum with attributes. Those attributes are the same ones that exist now.

Comment: And that's it? Only deprecation of namespace/enum will be available?

Comment: If you want new attributes standardized, go propose them. Compilers like GCC and Clang support more than the few standard ones. Anyway, you can read the [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4196.html) for motivation. I also have to amend my previous comment; I said enums, but I should have said enumerators.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed. The answer provided information that I found difficult to find (in a human-readable way) elsewhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently, If you were going to depreciate a particular enum value, you would need to rely on compiler extensions.  For example, in clang, you would specify deprecated enum values the following way:

```
enum OperationMode {
  OM_Invalid,
  OM_Normal,
  OM_Terrified __attribute__((deprecated)),
  OM_AbortOnError __attribute__((deprecated)) = 4
};
```

Once enums and namespaces support attributes, there will be a standard cross-compiler way of implementing similar functionality:

```
enum OperationMode {
  OM_Invalid,
  OM_Normal,
  OM_Terrified [[deprecated("re-named to invalid")]],
  OM_AbortOnError  [[deprecated("exceptions are used instead")]] = 4
};
```

Other attributes may one day find relevance to namespaces and enumerated values, but as the proposal writer states:

> This paper proposes resolving these issues by allowing attributes to
>   be specified on enumerators and namespaces, and extends the
>   [[deprecated]] attribute to apply to these entities, as was originally
>   intended.